# nav-tabs adjust width with elipses if a lot of tabs are present

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have nab-tabs, with ellipses on non-active tabs. My goal is to be able to nicely stack these tabs and squeeze the width as smaller as needed for it to occupy in one line. As of now when there are a lot of tabs present they're all over the place.

Problem:
[image]

This is my code.

```
.nav-tabs>li:not(.active)>a {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: 3px solid #9d9d9d;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 100%;
  width:4em;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.nav-tabs {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">

  <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
    {% block tab_buttons %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>

  <li role="presentation" class="{% if '/reports' in request.path %}active {% endif %}inverse"><a href="{% url 'sc:benchmarks:reports-list' benchmark.id %}" role="tab">Reports</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" class="{% if '/hosts' in request.path %}active {% endif %}inverse"><a href="{% url 'sc:benchmarks:hosts-list' benchmark.id %}" role="tab">Hosts</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" class="{% if '/rules' in request.path %}active{% endif %} inverse"><a href="{% url 'sc:benchmarks:rules-list' benchmark.id %}" role="tab">Rules</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" class="{% if '/summary' in request.path %}active {% endif %}inverse"><a href="{% url 'sc:benchmarks:summary' benchmark.id %}" role="tab">Summary</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" class="{% if '/incidents' in request.path %}active {% endif %}inverse"><a href="{% url 'sc:benchmarks:incidents-list' benchmark.id %}" role="tab">Incidents</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" class="{% if '/events' in request.path %}active {% endif %}inverse"><a href="{% url 'sc:benchmarks:events-list' benchmark.id %}" role="tab">Events</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" class="{% if '/aliases' in request.path %}active {% endif %}inverse"><a href="{% url 'sc:benchmarks:aliases-list' benchmark.id %}" role="tab">Aliases</a></li>
</ul>
```

Reports

Expected:
[image]

I'm happy to use jquery solution if needed to accomplish what I want.

Tabs are dynamic. Could be many.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for your CSS? I changed the items to be inline elements and applied the CSS selector to all `<li>` tags rather than the `<a>` tags.

```
.nav-tabs>li {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top: 3px solid #9d9d9d;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}

.nav-tabs {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this generic example, i think it will help:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.inline-text {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 150px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="inline-text"> Regular short string. </button>
  <button class="inline-text"> Regular short string. </button>
  <button class="inline-text"> Regular short string. </button>
  <button class="inline-text"> Regular short string. </button>
  <button class="inline-text"> Regular short string. </button>
  <button class="inline-text"> Regular short string. </button>
  <button class="inline-text"> Regular short string. </button>
  <button class="inline-text"> Regular short string. </button>
  <button class="inline-text"> Regular short string. </button>
  <button class="inline-text"> Regular short string. </button>
  <button class="inline-text"> Regular short string. </button>
  <button class="inline-text"> Regular short string. </button>
  <button class="inline-text"> Regular short string. </button>
  <button class="inline-text"> Regular short string. </button>

</div>
```

And with ul + li and some style to mimic links:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.inline-text {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 150px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li class="inline-text"> Regular short string. </li>
  <li class="inline-text"> Regular short string. </li>
  <li class="inline-text"> Regular short string. </li>
  <li class="inline-text"> Regular short string. </li>
  <li class="inline-text"> Regular short string. </li>
  <li class="inline-text"> Regular short string. </li>
  <li class="inline-text"> Regular short string. </li>
  <li class="inline-text"> Regular short string. </li>
  <li class="inline-text"> Regular short string. </li>
  <li class="inline-text"> Regular short string. </li>
  <li class="inline-text"> Regular short string. </li>
  <li class="inline-text"> Regular short string. </li>
  <li class="inline-text"> Regular short string. </li>
  <li class="inline-text"> Regular short string. </li>
</ul>
```

EDIT - change width dynamically function:

```js
var navLi = document.getElementsByClassName('inline-text');
function duplicate() {
  var clone = navLi[0].cloneNode(true);
  navLi[0].parentNode.appendChild(clone);
  for (var i=0; i < navLi.length; i++) {
    if (navLi.length > 5) {navLi[i].style.maxWidth = '150px';}
    if (navLi.length > 10) {navLi[i].style.maxWidth = '100px';}
    if (navLi.length > 15) {navLi[i].style.maxWidth = '50px';}
  }
}
document.getElementById('addTab').onclick = function() {duplicate()};
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;  
  padding: 5px 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-x: auto;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.inline-text {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: auto;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li class="inline-text"> Regular short string. </li>
</ul>
<hr />
<p> Demo purpose: click to <button id="addTab" onlick="duplicate()">Add Tab</button></p>
```

Comment: I prefer to use nav-tab, would this behave the same?

Comment: @Dilli added a list with some style to mimic yours.

Comment: the solution you purposed, if you have more li it just ends in the screen with eliipses, rather I'd like to create li width smaller with ellipsess [Reg..] or if more tabs [Regular Short...] so user can still access the tab

Comment: @ A. Meshu I'd like the width of each li to be smaller so they all fit in the screen.

Comment: @Dilli Do you mean without the scroll of the container element? How much li are there? Even on browseres - at the moment you have lot of opening tabs it put some arrow button in order to scrolll...

Comment: It's not going to have ALOT-ALOT of tabs, that's why I don't want to opt in for scroll. I just want a solution where it can handle at least 20 tabs fine. Also when there are 2 tabs I don't want my nav to be the same size, I want it to calibrate based on number of tabs and screen size, that's why i'm also open to jquery solution

Comment: appreciate your help! (:

Comment: @Dilli check updated answer. You can play with that: instead li.length use .container offsetWidth etc..